# How to create tab/flap pages in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm looking for help (tutorial) how to achieve tab/flap style pagination as seen on the attached picture. Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Ask the printer ;)

Comment: As Loic says, this is something you’ll have to figure out with the printer. It’s not something you can do just by doing something particular in InDesign—you have to mark in InDesign where and how the printer should cut the pages, _and you have to talk to the printer to make sure they know what to do_. Talk to the printer beforehand; they may have a preferred way of indicating these special croppings. (As an aside, that’s a very nice font.)

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate! I thought there's s functionality in InDesign or something.

Answer (score 1):

### There's no built-in option for this.

These are done by hand after discussing with your printer, or using a cutting template provided by them (in some cases it is possible to actually get these from the printer). Generally you will need to design the pages as full, uncut sheets of paper, make sure the background of the area to be trimmed is the same as the color of each tab. Then you need to overlay a cutting shape (die line), basicly a vector line in a special overprint Pantone color to indicate how each tab needs to be cut. Here's a [link](https://indesignsecrets.com/free-indesign-template-month-spiral-bound-booklet.php) to get you started researching this.